# Group arrays by parent ids object Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Need a help from Ramda community... I have an object array that I need to sort by "chapter_id" and after sorting, just remove "chapter_id":

```
const stuff = [
  { id: 1, title: "hello world", chapter_id: "4321" },
  { id: 2, title: "new title", chapter_id: "21" },
  { id: 3, title: "...", chapter_id: "33" },
  { id: 4, title: "huh!?", chapter_id: "14" },
  { id: 5, title: "From Earth", chapter_id: "11" },
  { id: 6, title: "alien", chapter_id: "11" },
  { id: 7, title: "Saturn", chapter_id: "11" },
  { id: 8, title: "Mars:/", chapter_id: "21" },
  { id: 9, title: "damn", chapter_id: "3" },
  { id: 10, title: "test", chapter_id: "11" },
  { id: 11, title: "ramda heeeelp", chapter_id: "31" },
  { id: 12, title: "hello?", chapter_id: "21" }
]
```

---

**And as result I want to get this object:**

```
{
  "3": [
    {
      "id": "9",
      "title": "damn"
    }
  ],
  "11": [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "title": "From Earth"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "title": "alien"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "title": "Saturn"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "title": "test"
    }
  ],
  "14": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "title": "huh!?"
    }
  ],
  "21": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "new title"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "title": "Mars:/"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "title": "hello?"
    }
  ],
  "31": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "ramda heeeelp"
    }
  ],
  "33": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "..."
    }
  ],
  "4321": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "hello world"
    }
  ]
}
```

How I struggled with this:

```
let object = {};

map(({ chapter_id }) => {
  const composed = compose(
    map(evolve({ id: toString })), //here id is converted to a string
    filter(c => c.chapter_id === chapter_id),
  );
  object[chapter_id] = composed(stuff)
}, stuff);
```

**My result:**

```js
{
  "3": [
    {
      "id": "9",
      "title": "damn",
      "chapter_id": "3" //Dissoc this
    }
  ],
  "11": [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "title": "From Earth",
      "chapter_id": "11" //dissoc this
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "title": "alien",
      "chapter_id": "11"  //and this
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "title": "Saturn",
      "chapter_id": "11" //and this
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "title": "test",
      "chapter_id": "11" //and this
    }
  ],
  "14": [
    {
      "id": "4",
      "title": "huh!?",
      "chapter_id": "14" //and this
    }
  ],
  "21": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "new title",
      "chapter_id": "21" //and this
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "title": "Mars:/",
      "chapter_id": "21" //and this
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "title": "hello?",
      "chapter_id": "21" //and this
    }
  ],
  "31": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "ramda heeeelp",
      "chapter_id": "31" //and this!!!!!!
    }
  ],
  "33": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "...",
      "chapter_id": "33" //and this..
    }
  ],
  "4321": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "hello world",
      "chapter_id": "4321" //and this:(
    }
  ]
}
```

It works but I can't dissoc "chapter_id" from each object, does anyone know how to solve this? :Δ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ori Drori notes, this is the likely Ramda method:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  groupBy(prop('chapter_id')),
  map(map(dissoc('chapter_id'))),
)
```

But if you need to actually sort the keys, as your answer suggests, then it will take a bit more processing.  You might try something like this:

```js
const transform = pipe (
  groupBy(prop('chapter_id')),
  map(map(dissoc('chapter_id'))),
  toPairs,
  sortBy(pipe(head, Number)),
  fromPairs
)

const stuff = [{id: 1, title: "hello world", chapter_id: "4321"}, {id: 2, title: "new title", chapter_id: "21"}, {id: 3, title: "...", chapter_id: "33"}, {id: 4, title: "huh!?", chapter_id: "14"}, {id: 5, title: "From Earth", chapter_id: "11"}, {id: 6, title: "alien", chapter_id: "11"}, {id: 7, title: "Saturn", chapter_id: "11"}, {id: 8, title: "Mars: /", chapter_id: "21"}, {id: 9, title: "damn", chapter_id: "3"}, {id: 10, title: "test", chapter_id: "11"}, {id: 11, title: "ramda heeeelp", chapter_id: "31"}, {id: 12, title: "hello?", chapter_id: "21"}]

console.log (
  transform (stuff)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, groupBy, prop, map, dissoc, toPairs, sortBy, head, fromPairs} = R </script>
```

That sorting line could be written in many ways.  Perhaps

```js
sort(lift(subtract)(head, head)),
```

or just

```js
sort(([a], [b]) => a - b),
```

And obviously if you were so inclined, you could pull out a `sortByKeys` function like this:

```js
const sortByKeys = (fn) => pipe(toPairs, sortBy(fn), fromPairs)
```

`sortByKeys` is not a likely candidate for inclusion in Ramda, which really prefers to think of objects as unordered collections of name-value pairs.  But it could easily go in your own helper library.

Comment: Sorting an object with numeric keys is not needed due to the [objects's traversal order of integer indices in ES6](https://2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html#integer-indices). Remove the sorting code, and the result won't change. It will however effect non integer indices, since they respect the order of entry.

Comment: Hi Scott! Thanks for your answer, it's really helpful for me. I ran a new problem, can you please check it? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58683743/9464680

Comment: @OriDrori: Yes, but only because they are small strings containing only digits.  If they were stringified floats or plain strings or pretty much anything else, that wouldn't work.   But this technique can be extended to any keys we can sort.

Answer (score 3):

With Ramda you can group by the `key`, and then map the groups, and dissoc the `key` from all objects:

```js
const { pipe, groupBy, prop, map, dissoc } = R;

const fn = key => pipe(
  groupBy(prop(key)), // group by the key
  map(map(dissoc(key))) // remove the key from all objects in all groups
);

const stuff = [{"id":1,"title":"hello world","chapter_id":"4321"},{"id":2,"title":"new title","chapter_id":"21"},{"id":3,"title":"...","chapter_id":"33"},{"id":4,"title":"huh!?","chapter_id":"14"},{"id":5,"title":"From Earth","chapter_id":"11"},{"id":6,"title":"alien","chapter_id":"11"},{"id":7,"title":"Saturn","chapter_id":"11"},{"id":8,"title":"Mars:/","chapter_id":"21"},{"id":9,"title":"damn","chapter_id":"3"},{"id":10,"title":"test","chapter_id":"11"},{"id":11,"title":"ramda heeeelp","chapter_id":"31"},{"id":12,"title":"hello?","chapter_id":"21"}];

const result = fn('chapter_id')(stuff);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all the finite task is not properly described :) What you really want (based on the *result I want to get* section) is to **normalize (or restructure) the array of objects into an object, which have the `chapter_id` as a key, and the value is an array of the associated records of the `stuff` array with that `chapter_id`**

On my opinion, your solution is cool and seems like a more functional, but in this particular case I've probably will give a preference to the simple `reduce` function, which is more readable...

```
reduce((acc, {chapter_id, ...rest}) => {
  const isInitialized = !!acc[chapter_id];
  if (isInitialized) {
    acc[chapter_id].push(rest); 
  } else {
    acc[chapter_id] = [rest];
  }
  return acc;
}, {}, stuff);
```