# Find an object by id in array Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

For example I have something like:

```
const stuff = {
  "31": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "ramda heeeelp"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "title": "ramda 123"
    }
  ],
  "33": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "..."
    }
  ],
  "4321": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "hello world"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to find object with id 11. How I did:

```
map(key => find(propEq('id', 11))(stuff[key]), keys(stuff))
```

However it returns `[{..object with id 11..}, undefined, undefined]` due to map. Ok, we could check if object isn't undefined, but it isn't clear as I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the values of the object, flatten the array of arrays, and use find and propEq to get the object:

```js
const { pipe, values, flatten, find, propEq } = R

const findById = id => pipe(
  values,
  flatten,
  find(propEq({ id }))
)

const data = {"31":[{"id":"11","title":"ramda heeeelp"},{"id":"12","title":"ramda 123"}],"33":[{"id":"3","title":"..."}],"4321":[{"id":"1","title":"hello world"}]}

const result = findById('11')(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is a new issue, could you take a look? Thanks! - https://stackoverflow.com/q/58693528/9464680