# Update object value Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

In previous question I tried to group arrays by parent ids and then remove them from each object - [Group arrays by parent ids object Ramda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58682137/9464680).

But now I have a new issue. For example I want to update title in object with id 12.

**My data model:**

```
const stuff = {
  "31": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "ramda heeeelp"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "title": "ramda 123"
    }
  ],
  "33": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "..."
    }
  ],
  "4321": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "hello world"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Attempts:**

```
const alter = (id, key, value) => pipe(
  values,
  flatten,
  update(...) // <= end of my attempts
  // then group again
)

alter('12', 'title', 'new heading 123')(stuff)
```

Comment: Ramda is designed with immutable data in mind. Can't you just use `assocPath(['12', 'title'], 'new heading 123')` to get a copy of the object with the value replaced with a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [lenses](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/lenses-b85976cb0534) here:

1. Over: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over
2. Set: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set

```js
const titleLens = R.curry((key, id, data) => R.lensPath([
  key, 
  R.findIndex(R.whereEq({ id }), R.propOr([], key, data)), 
  'title'
]));

// ----
const stuff = {
  "31": [
    {
      "id": "11",
      "title": "ramda heeeelp"
    },
    {
      "id": "12",
      "title": "ramda 123"
    }
  ],
  "33": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "..."
    }
  ],
  "4321": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "hello world"
    }
  ]
}

const title3111 = titleLens('31', '11', stuff);
const result = R.set(title3111, 'DID RAMDA HELP YOU?', stuff);

console.log('result', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks to ramda and u!:D

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be best done with a custom [`lens`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens).  Here I write a lens creator (`idInObjLens`) that focuses on the object with the correct id, regardless of what group it falls in.  Then I write `myLens` to accept an id and a property name and return you a lens that focuses on that property of the object.

With those, we can use Ramda's [`view`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#view), [`set`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set), and [`over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) to see the value, set the value, or update the value with a function:

```js
const idInObjLens = (id) => lens (
  (obj) => {
    let index = -1
    const child = find (value => (index = findIndex (propEq ('id', id), value)) > -1, values (obj) )
    if (child) return child [index]
  },
  (val, obj) => {
    let index = -1
    const [key, value] = find (([key, value]) => (index = findIndex (propEq ('id', id), value)) > -1, toPairs (obj) )
    return assoc (key, update (index, val, value), obj)
  },
)


const myLens = (id, key) => compose (idInObjLens (id), lensProp (key))

const stuff = {"31": [{"id": "11", "title": "ramda heeeelp"},  {"id": "12", "title": "ramda 123"}], "33": [{"id": "3", "title": "..."}], "4321": [{"id": "1", "title": "hello world"}]};

[
    view (myLens ('12', 'title'), stuff),
    set  (myLens ('3',  'title'), 'new heading 123', stuff),
    over (myLens ('1',  'title'), toUpper, stuff),
] .forEach (x => console .log (x))
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {lens, find, findIndex, propEq, values, toPairs, assoc, update, compose, lensProp, view, set, over, toUpper } = R</script>
```

Note that the `set` and `over` will only work if that id actually exists.  You might want to check using `view` first.

`myLens` is simple; it's just how lens composition works.  (Notice that it seems to flow backward from regular compose; the [technical reasons](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/23x3f3/lenses_dont_compose_backwards/) are interesting, but beyond the scope of an SO answer.)  But `idInObjLens` is more complex.  As with all lenses, it takes a getter and a setter.  Both of them simultaneously find the object key that contains the item with the id and the index of that key in the array associated with that object key.  The getter simply returns the value.  The setter uses [`assoc`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assoc) to update the outer object and [`update`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#update) to update the array inside it.  All other nested objects are simply returned by reference.

This is not code to be proud of.  It works, and of course that's the main thing.  But I really don't like calculating the array index as a side-effect of the `find` call.  Yet calculating it a second time just seems overkill.  I also don't really like the name `idInObjLens` and I always feel that if I don't have a good name, I'm missing something fundamental.  (I don't have the same objection to `myLens`, as I assume you will have a better name for this for your use-case.)

The big difference between this and the solution from Hitmand is that this lens does not require you to know up-front which key in the outer object holds the item with your id.  That adds a fair bit of complexity to the solution, but makes its API much more flexible.

Comment: hm, in my case I'd prefer assocPath

Comment: `assocPath` is fine... if you already know the id associated with the group.  This is designed for the case when you don't know it and have to find it.

Answer (score 2):

You map all array inside properties, and use `R.when` to evolve all objects with matching `id`s, and replace the property's (`title` in your case) value:

```js
const { curry, map, when, propEq, evolve, always } = R

const fn = curry((id, prop, content) =>
  map(map( // map all objects of all properties
    when(
      propEq('id', id),  // if the id of an object matches
      evolve({ [prop]: always(content) })) // evolve it's property to the content
    )
  ))

const data = {"31":[{"id":"11","title":"ramda heeeelp"},{"id":"12","title":"ramda 123"}],"33":[{"id":"3","title":"..."}],"4321":[{"id":"1","title":"hello world"}]}

const result = fn('12', 'title', 'new heading 123')(data)

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```